# Can we extend liferay session through Java Code?

Tags: session, timeout, liferay

Can we extend session through Java Code?

I found the code to extend the session through javascript. But I've doubt , Can we extend session through Java Code? I need to extend the session through java only.

Can anyone help me???
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The session is maintained by the application server. If you need longer sessions, you can configure them in your appserver.

The application server implicitly extends a session whenever it sees a http request with that session id, that's why extending the session through javascript works: It just triggers some http request and counts on the side effect of extending the session.

On an application server you typically don't have custom threads running anyway, so you shouldn't count on this to help you. It's the wrong place to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

No you can not extend session timeout through Java because session is maintained by application server.
If you want to extned sesseion, you can configured them in application server.